# Why in the second run of the script, it is first displayed "Not OK", and then displayed "OK"?

Tags: perl

I want to write a regex with output "OK" and "Not OK", without using constructs if, else:

`validator_2.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use utf8;
use locale;
use warnings;
use 5.10.0;

my $input = <STDIN>;
say "OK" if $input =~ m/^\+7\s\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/ || say "Not OK";
```

```
$ echo "+7 (921) 123-45-67"|./validator_2.pl 
OK
$ echo "+7 (921) 123-45-67888888"|./validator_2.pl 
Not OK
OK
```

Comment: Note: phone number validation is more complicated than in provided code sample. If you use code sample for educational purpose then chosen pattern specifies -- `(begin of the line)+7 (ddd) ddd-dd-dd(end of line)`. Problem description is quite obscure and does not explain in enough details what you try to achieve. [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: In second script run comparison/matching will be negative and you specify `||  say 'Not Ok'` which will be executed (successfully) and result if operation becomes `true` what leads to execution `say Ok`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please study the following demonstration sample code

Note: phone number validation quite complicated task, regex is not right approach for this purpose

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $re = qr/^\+7\s\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/;

while( my $input = <DATA> ) {
    chomp($input);
    say "$input : ", ($input =~ /$re/) ? 'Ok' : 'Not OK';
}


__DATA__
+7 (921) 123-45-67
+7 (921) 123-45-67888888
```

Output

```
+7 (921) 123-45-67 : Ok
+7 (921) 123-45-67888888 : Not OK
```